# Preventing team from accessing Gmail (SMTP auth)

Tags: php, security

What is the best way to prevent developers from accessing the email SMTP information for an account we'd like to use for sending emails to customers?

I am thinking of using the native `mail()` function in PHP, and setup the credentials outside the code, in the php.ini file where the developers have no access.

The problem now is that the sysadmin can see the password.  I am wondering if there's such thing as SMTP authentication using the OAuth tokens or something similar.

Comment: What if anything goes wrong? Who are you going to ask to fix it since no one can access your system?

Comment: You could have an intermediate mail server that they send mail to, and which re-forwards to GMail. They would of course have access to those credentials. However if you don't trust your sysadmins you have problems, and if you make it clear you don't trust your sysadmins, you might have even more problems.

Comment: the thing is, you trust the sys admin, they'll maintain the authentication information, but you don't trust the programmers. it's like giving your login info to some Android app, rather than using OAuth, that's what I'm trying to find out, is there a way to provent the programmers from seeing the SMTP information?